# APP_PLATFORM is ignored

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am getting the following error:

```
Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-24 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 8 in jni/../AndroidManifest.xml
```

when executing:
    ndk-build -C src/main/

but APP_PLATFORM is set to 8:

```
⋊> ~/g/gobandroid-ai-gnugo on master ⨯ cat src/main/jni/Application.mk                                                                                   15:22:57
APP_PROJECT_PATH := $(call my-dir)/.. 

#project
APP_MODULES      := gnuGo-3.8
APP_OPTIM    := release
APP_BUILD_SCRIPT := $(call my-dir)/project/Android.mk
APP_ABI :=  armeabi armeabi-v7a x86 mips x86_64 mips64 arm64-v8a
APP_PLATFORM := android-8
```

Comment: Have you verified that your `Application.mk` actually is used in the build. For example, if you add another line after `APP_PLATFORM := android-8` that just contains some gibberish, does the build still succeed?

Comment: Yes - and it seems to be special to android-8 - android-9 throws Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-9 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 8 in jni/../AndroidManifest.xml - I think I just update the minSDK to 9 ..

Comment: Which NDK release are you using? NDK r12-beta1 doesn't have anything below `android-9` in the platforms directory.

Comment: Ah now I see - just updated to r12 - thanks for your input! If you add this as an answer I will accept this with pleasure ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `android-8` platform appears to have been obsoleted by the NDK developers. It's not available in r12-beta1, nor in r13-beta1. The oldest available platform in these releases of the NDK is `android-9`.